# IOS ipa file showing white screen and stuck at that while running with cable works fine

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, build

IOS ipa file showing white screen and stuck at that while running with cable works fine.

I had developed an app using flutter, i open that app's IOS module in XCODE ,
than i am proceed to making an IPA file for ad-hoc or some specific devices , which UDID added in my apple developer account.

i installed that IPA in my device and its stuck at blank white screen nothing happens ahead.
while i run my app through cable it works fine no problem is there showing.

i can not identifying the issue please help.

I am new to IOS ... so is there any method for debugging the Installed IPA???? is it possible?? if not than what is solution for it ...help me !!

Comment: Adhoc profile does not run app directly from xcode. I am assuming you are killing app by pressing home button twice after app installation using adhoc profile. If not then kindly kill app first and run again.

Comment: you can not send .ipa file in any iphone device. for testing in other iphone you just upload your ipa file on this site "https://www.diawi.com/" to for free internal testing for developer.

Comment: @Niravshekhaliya  yes i have tried this uploaded my ipa on diawi than install from it in device still it shows white screen only.

Comment: Did you try to run it locally with `--release` which is the default for the IPA?

Comment: plz recreate your ipa file and try it...

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by applying the `--release` flag.

I got the idea from Flutter developers. They have the same problem of "black screen". They solved this problem by using the `--release` option.

If you use monorepo library nx, you can apply the `--release` mode by making the `dev` option `false` as follow:

[image]